# Add video url in Import magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, product, import

Is there any way to add video url in magento2 bulk import.

if that is not possible how can i add product video programmatically in magento2

Comment: have you tried using Magento 2's API? Specifically /rest/V1/products/{SKU}/media ?